# VB Script will not run in my HTA app....only turns screen white

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

I am trying to run a VB script in my HTA app but every time submit is selected the only thing that happens is my screen turns white. I have been over the script many times but can't find out what is causing this to occur. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Code is below:

```
<script language="VBScript" 
  Public Sub RunScript() 
  Set objWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
  strCMD = "cscript.exe c:\C:\Users\william.smith03\Documents\HTML5 Printer            Install\Printer     (file:///c:/C:/Users/william.smith03/Documents/HTML5%20Printer%20Install/Printer) Install   v3.7.vbs" 
  objWSH.Run(strCMD)  

End Sub 
</script>
```

Comment: so..the printer install script that I built
I'm trying to wrap that all up with an HTA file
to pretty it up
is there a better language to use to install printers than VBS?

Comment: Your script path looks messed up. It as `file:` and `c:c:` in it. Did you try fixing that?

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the `>` character at the end of first line.

If you are sure that all of those empty spaces and characters inside the directory path are ok, then this will work:

```
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub RunScript() 
        app  = "cscript.exe"
        args = """c:\C:\Users\william.smith03\Documents\HTML5 Printer            Install\Printer     (file:///c:/C:/Users/william.smith03/Documents/HTML5%20Printer%20Install/Printer) Install   v3.7.vbs"""
        CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run(app & " " & args)  
    End Sub 
</script>
```

Comment: I can try both resolutions and see what happens.

Comment: @Drew see update before trying, you need to ensure that the arguments are enclosed with double-quotes 'cause it is an argument which contains spaces.

Comment: I have tried both resolutions (removing c:c:, and also the script Elektro created or fixed) Still having the same issue. Once i run the script my screen goes white.